# html/template call method on value directly

Tags: go

I would like to call and print the result of Format on Date directly within the template without writing a boiler plate method for the Foo struct.

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
    "time"
)

type Foo struct {
    Date time.Time
}

func main() {
    foo := Foo{time.Now()}
    tmpl, err := template.New("test").Parse("{{.Date}}")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, foo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/_NHWYjK_1x)

Answer (score 3):

You can call .Format on the Date Object:

`"{{.Date.Format \"Jan 2, 2006 at 3:04pm (MST)\" }}"`

http://play.golang.org/p/P4kKfZ5UN5

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
    "time"
)

type Foo struct {
    Date time.Time
}

func main() {
    foo := Foo{time.Now()}
    tmpl, err := template.New("test").Parse("{{.Date.Format \"Jan 2, 2006 at 3:04pm (MST)\" }}")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, foo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: I was having the most trouble actually getting this to print from my actual file through the response writer. May have been the lack of escapes? I'll try this when I get a chance, thank you.